# Youtube bot in Javascript

Tags: javascript

OK, so I have some Javascript code, but the thing is, I don't know if it works or not. The Javascript code is supposed to :

- remove the ".mp4" extension from every title
- change my video category
- put the same description in all of the videos
- put the same keywords in all of the videos

So, that Javascript code should be run on the Youtube upload page. You log in, select videos to upload and you get to your upload page. So, could someone test this script out for me (I am not familiar with testing the script)?

Code :

```
var i = prompt("How many videos have you got?", "");
function remove_mp4()
{
   titleElems=document.getElementsByName("title");
   for(i=0;i<titleElems.length;i++)
   {
       titleInner=titleElems[i].innerHTML;
       titleElems[i].innerHTML=titleInner.replace(titleInner.match(".mp4"), "");
   }
}
for (var x = 0; x < i; i++)
{
    document.getElementsByName("description")[x].value = "Visit me on my web-site :\
    \
                                                          http://www.sample.com/";
     document.getElementsByName("keywords")[x].value = prompt("Enter your keywords : ","");
    catChildNodes=document.getElementsByName("category")[x].childNodes;
    catChildNotes[x + 1].removeAttribute("selected");
    for(y=0;y<catChildNodes.length;y++)
    {
       if(catChildNodes[y].value="27") 
       {
          catChildNodes[y].setAttribute("selected",""); 
       }
   }
}
remove_mp4();
```

Also, there is one thing I notice and that is that my URL from "//" these //www.sample.com/ is considered as an comment (it is colored green in Notepad++).

So, could someone fix the comment bug and test the script to see if it works (on Youtube upload page)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We're not a software testing service.

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar, so it would be a huge help.

Comment: "here, swallow this pill for me. I don't know what it does, but it'd be hugely helpful if you did this". While nothing in that code looks suspect, exactly how do you plan to make this run ON youtube? Google's not likely to let you embed random scripts in an upload page.

Comment: Ask questions to learn how to test, or how to fix an error, asking someone else to code for you is insulting.

Comment: OK, but just to ask you, could I run this code on Youtube from GreaseMonkey? The reason I created it is because it would speed up my upload process a lot.

Comment: @TheGhost: Have you tried running it in GreaseMonkey?

Comment: @Rocket: No. Can I ask you, how to run it in GreaseMonkey (can you explain it please)?

Comment: @TheGhost: I'm not sure.  It's been a while since I've last used it.  Sorry =/

Answer (score 4):

Your line

```
document.getElementsByName("description")[x].value = "Visit me on my web-site :

                                                          http://www.sample.com/";
```

is not a valid string in JavaScript.

Comment: Strings in JavaScript cannot contain (unescaped) new lines.  You need to escape the new line, add a `\ ` to the end of the 1st 2 lines.

Comment: or you could use the actual newline character '\n'

Comment: OK, fixed it. But just to ask, can I run the script over Greasemonkey?